# JCheckBox Text overlaps custom icon

Tags: java, swing, icons, jcheckbox

I have a JCheckBox with a custom icon. The dimensions of the icon are 32x32 pixels.

When I set some text with horizontal alignment RIGHT, the text is not respecting the icon's width.

[screenshot of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lX0y7.png)

[image]

How can I make sure the text does not overlap with the icon and instead be layout next to the icon?

My checkbox is rather straightforward:

```
JCheckBox cbx = new JCheckBox(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(pathToFile)));
cbx.setText("some label");
```

Thanks.

Comment: For better reproduction of your problem please provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Trying to build a SSCCE helped. My problem seems to be specific to MPS, where I encounter it when I integrate a custom JCheckBox into my language editor. SInce I cannot reproduce the issue in a standalone Java application, I assume it is a layout issue within MPS. I will follow up on that in the MPS forum. Thanks.

Comment: In case someone wants to follow the breadcrumbs, I asked the question in the MPS forum now: http://forum.jetbrains.com/thread/Meta-Programming-System-5050